# "The handle is invalid" when invoking PSExec using PHP's exec function

Tags: php, psexec, sysinternals

Alright, I've read all the forums and other SO posts but to no avail. Been banging my head on the wall for this. I have a very minimal PHP page like this:

```
 <?php
    exec('PsExec.exe -accepteula \\\\192.168.10.11 -u "administrator" -p "Ph0nYP@sSw0rd" hostname', $output, $returnVar);   
    print_r($output);
    print_r('Return value is: ' . $returnVar);
?>
```

It is supposed to simply execute the `hostname`command on 192.168.10.11. I execute the page using `php.exe mypage.php` but this always results in the following:

```
Couldn't access 192.168.10.11:
The handle is invalid.
Connecting to 192.168.10.11...
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

- I have verified that PSExec works by running the same command from
  outside of the php page i.e. `PsExec.exe \\192.168.10.11 -u "administrator" -p "Ph0nYP@sSw0rd" hostname`
- I have verified that the administrator account has access to the
  target machine 192.168.10.12 in Control Panel > User Accounts > Give 
  other users access to this computer
- I have watched a wireshark capture when I execute the PHP page but there is no traffic. So I don't know if it's even successfully launching PSExec.
- I have verified the credentials work by going to Run >
  \\192.168.10.12\c$ and entering the creds. I am able to browse the
  folder.
- I have tried using PHP's shell_exec and get the same results

So I know **the account has access**, **the creds are good**, and that **PSExec is working**. It seems that once I wrap it inside a php page that something breaks. What does "The handle is invalid" mean here? And what else can I do to troubleshoot or work around it? My goal is to ultimately execute a powershell script on the target box that will use parameters in a POST request to the page. While I'm not married to my current method I'm still very curious as to why it's failing.

Comment: Does your php run as an administrator? Try running xampp/wamp as administrator. For testing cli you can run a cmd prompt as admin then  >php yourfile.php

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot to mention that. Everything is running as admin already, including XAMPP and cmd prompt I am testing with.